# Corelated Filters with Firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing a query in firebase, but I want to add `where()` condition based on a condition. Like, if some values are entered then `where()` should be included otherwise basic query should run. Below is my code. I checked using console.log if condition is passed but the query returns all results. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
  let t = savedTopifyPapers
  if (queryParams.value.key && queryParams.value.value) {
    t.orderBy('timeStamp')
      .limit(limit.value)
      .where(queryParams.value.key.toString(), '==', queryParams.value.value)
  } else {
    t.orderBy('timeStamp').limit(limit.value)
  }
  t.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    const _lastDoc = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]
    firstVisible.value = snapshot.docs[0]
    if (_lastDoc) {
      lastDoc.value = _lastDoc
    }
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      loadingData.value = false
    }
    papersData.value = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data()
      const id = doc.id
      loadingData.value = false
      return { id, ...data }
    })
    papersDataLength.value = papersData.value.length
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase queries follow a builder pattern, where every time you call `where` or `orderBy` it returns a new object. Since you never store this new object, you always end up running the original "query": `let t = savedTopifyPapers`.

To fix the problem, assign the new object to `t`:

```
let t = savedTopifyPapers
if (queryParams.value.key && queryParams.value.value) {
  t = t.orderBy('timeStamp')
    .limit(limit.value)
    .where(queryParams.value.key.toString(), '==', queryParams.value.value)
} else {
  t = t.orderBy('timeStamp').limit(limit.value)
}
...
```